# call hello_word in linux from php script

Tags: php, linux, shell, unix

I'm trying to use a php file to call a shell script. First time.

```
#Shell script:
#!/bin/bash
echo "Hello, World!"


//PHP
echo "call shell";
$output = shell_exec('get_logs.sh');
echo "<pre>".$output."</pre>";
```

On the PHP page, I see the "call shell" printed. But no hello world and no errors. Can I see the errors somewhere or do I have a syntax error I'm not aware of?

Comment: works for me. maybe you can try added /bin/bash before.

Comment: @mcuadros What does that line do? I thought it was a comment. Does it tell the program where to look for someething?

Comment: I guess `shell_exec()` has been disabled in your web server. What gives you `var_dump(function_exists('shell_exec'));` ?

Comment: Any way i suggest you use http://php.net/manual/es/function.proc-open.php instead shell_exec will be a more secure execution

Comment: @mcuadros What is more secure when using `proc_open()` ?

Comment: With proc_open will give you more control of the execution, a shell_exec is very old function proc_open is a modern implementation. Maybe secure is not the best word.

Comment: @hek2mgl `boolean true` :/

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have to specify a full path to your shell script.

i.e.

> /usr/local/bin/get_logs.sh

But it depends where you put it.

Make sure the script is marked executable
i.e. `chmod +x /usr/local/bin/get_logs.sh`

Make sure `#!/bin/bash` is the first line in the file, i.e. remove "#Shell script:"

---

Thomas, your script should simply contain:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Hello, World!"
```

After you've created it. Mark it with execute permissions.

i.e. in a terminal run "chmod +x [filename]"

Where filename is the name of the script which can include the path also.

Comment: Okay, sounds good. So my shell script should be `#!/bin/bash
chmod +x /usr/local/bin/get_logs.sh
echo 'hello world'` on three separate lines? thanks!

Comment: And my PHP is two lines in the same directory: `<?php
echo "call shell";
$output = shell_exec('/opt/httpd/htdocs/get_logs.sh');
?>`

Comment: what does `bin/bash` refer to? Should that link to a particular directory? there's bin/bash in the directory I'm running this script in.

Answer (score 0):

you probably need to check if the assigned user for PHP/Apache has execute access to the file.

Comment: yes that just shows that you have shell access. I was referring to the permissions/ownership of your gt_logs.sh. What permissions does it have and who owns that file?

Comment: That looks like this `-rw-r--r--`

Comment: try using the full path to the file also in your PHP.

Comment: Okay, and what should the full contents of the shell file be please. I'm confused about if I need any of this business `#!/bin/bash chmod +x /usr/local/bin/get_logs.sh echo 'hello world'`..